# AngularFire - manage child_added and other events on $asArray

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Hello guys !

I wanted to do something pretty simple : display the last 10 posts with the newer at the top, and when someone posts a new one, display a bar "click here to see x new posts" that when clicked displays the new ones.

My problem : when a new posts enters Firebase, it immediately displays on screen (using the ng-repeat on the array of the scope linked to the array from Firebase), and takes the older of the 10 elements out.

```
$firebase(ref.limitToLast(10)).$asArray().$loaded().then(function(messagesData) { ... }
```

I can detect the change using

```
messagesData.$watch(function(data) {
    console.log("data changed!", data, messagesData);

    if(data.event == "child_added") {
        // work here
    }
});
```

But I can't figure out how to do what I'm trying to, nor did I find it in the doc. Thanks for any help !

Comment: You won't be able to do this with AngularFire, which is a simple bindings library. You'll need to drop down to the [Firebase API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/) and utilize the query tools to create your own array. You will monitor child_added events, but only update the array placed in $scope when the appropriate control is clicked. Also, writing an app to create twitter feeds is beyond the scope of SO.

Comment: I think I found a nice way to do it using AngularFire, after 2 full days of work on it, I will try it tomorrow and post the answer if it's good. Thanks for your help, Kato. What do you mean by "beyond the scope of SO" ?

Comment: It simply means that the scope of the question is pretty broad, difficult to address in SO (stack overflows) Q&A format.

Comment: @Kato it would be great if you could review my answer below and say if you want it's efficient enough or did I miss something huge ? So far it works at least in my tests...

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so, there is a solution. It's possible not to have everything in sync while still enjoying the use of AngularFire for the current elements. Here is how.

Start by getting the messages you want to display at the beginning :

```
$firebase(ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(nbMessages)).$asArray().$loaded().then(function(messagesData) { ......
```

Then link them to another array one by one using foreach :

```
angular.forEach(messagesData, function(value, key) {
    messagesDataReturn[key] = value;
    // get any other data you need for that message (user name, etc...
});
```

This will keep every element iterated in sync. So if there is something like a counter of likes, they will be updated live.

Finally add a watcher :

```
messagesData.$watch(function(data) {
    if(data.event == "child_added") {
        var newLine = messagesData.filter(function ( obj ) {
            return obj.$id === data.key;
        })[0];

        // add any needed data for this new line

        $rootScope.$broadcast('list:updated', newLine);
    }
});
```

In your controller you just have to listen to the broadcast :

```
$scope.newData = [];
$scope.$on('list:updated', function (event, data) {
    $scope.newData.push(data);
});
```

You can then use $scope.newData to display the way to show the new messages and onclick merge this array with your main one on the scope, so the new messages appears.

Hope this helps someone !